# Getting and updating the value of the PreferredSize property

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, scroll, scrollbar

Good afternoon!

[A visual example if AutoScroll = true;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkx3Y.gif)

[A visual example if AutoScroll = false;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axka2.gif)

Please tell me how to get / calculate / or make the value of Panel.PreferredSize property update if Panel.AutoScroll = false?

Comment: Check the [PreferredSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.preferredsize) property.

Comment: PreferredSize property doesn't fit.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what that means. The `PreferredSize` returns the full size of a ScrollableControl, including the the area occupied by child Controls not visible on screen. The `DisplayRectangle` is the same as the `ClientRectangle` when Scrollbars are not used, otherwise is the same as the `PreferredSize` except the scroll offset. So you have `[Panel].VerticalScroll.Maximum = [Panel].PreferredSize.Height - [Panel].ClientSize.Height`. Then you just set the vertical offset: `[Panel].VerticalScroll.Value = 100`, if what you want to do is to scroll a ScrollableControl without Scrollbars.

Comment: I think managed to find the right value for VERTICAL SCROLL: PANEL.VerticalScroll.Maximum = PANEL.GetPreferredSize(flp_Container.Size).Height - PANEL.Size.Height; VScrolBar1.Maximum = flp_Container.VerticalScroll.Maximum;

Comment: Thank you for the tip about the "PrefferedSize" property.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void flp_Container_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e) {
    flp_Container.VerticalScroll.Maximum = flp_Container.GetPreferredSize(flp_Container.Size).Height - flp_Container.Size.Height;
    VScrolBar1.Maximum = flp_Container.VerticalScroll.Maximum;           
}
```